# Django + nginx + gunicorn error while IMAGE PROCESSING [ upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream ]

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am using Django, and I believe it is not an issue from Django side.

Simply upload an image (~500kb) using a Model Form, and using OpenCV just convert it into the grayscale (plus many more if this works).

I have configured using nginx and gunicorn and all functionalities works except file uploading and editing.

ERROR: upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 174.***.***.194, server: **.com, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "**.com", referrer: "http://****.com/"

Configuration-----------------------

`/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=shubham
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/shubham/editor/src
ExecStart=/home/shubham/editor/venv/bin/gunicorn \
        --access-logfile - \
        --workers 3 \
        --timeout 600 \
        --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
        src.wsgi:application
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;

        client_max_body_size 10000M;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        client_body_buffer_size 10000M;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 10000M;
        send_timeout 300s;

        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascr>...

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/editor`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ****.com;

        client_max_body_size 10000M;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 10000M;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/shubham/editor/src/static;
        }

        location /media/ {
                root /home/shubham/editor/src/media;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";


                proxy_read_timeout 300s;
                proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
                client_max_body_size 10000M;
                client_body_buffer_size 10000M;
                proxy_max_temp_file_size 10000M;
                send_timeout 300s;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

Error log `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2023/02/03 06:29:27 [error] 2479#2479: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 174.***.***.194, server: ****.com, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "****.com", referrer: "http://****.com/"
```

Please Help me out, all the configuration files are available above.

Comment: You want to include the `/etc/nginx/mime.types` also inside your static and media blocks. I think thats why it can't deal with the header of your images.

Comment: @Tarquinius, thank you very much for your reply, but it didn't work. Any other guesses?